# How can I make Intellij IDEA lag less when opening big files?

Tags: performance, intellij-idea, large-files, intellij-14

I have a need to open a 5500 line long code file in Intellij (before you ask, not my code, can't refactor now).

While the file is open the whole IDE becomes sluggish and nothing wants to respond without a delay of 3 seconds. It is quite annoying to debug like this.

Is there a specific tune geared towards improving it's handling of super large files? I mean Excel can open 65000 row file, why can't IntelliJ handle 10% of that?

Comment: Disable inspections, buy more cores, https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241235-Reporting-performance-problems

Comment: Allocate more memory to IDEA process by setting bigger `-Xmx` value in `.vmoptions` file (via [Help | Edit Custom VM Options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) action). Also you can mark the file as a plain text: https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2011/04/exclude-single-file/ for IDE not to analyze it, or set highlighting level to just syntax: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html

Answer (score 2):

Allocate more memory to IDEA process by setting bigger `-Xmx` value in `.vmoptions` file (via [Help | Edit Custom VM Options](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869) action). Also you can [mark the file as a plain text](https://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2011/04/exclude-single-file/) for IDE not to analyze it, or [set highlighting level](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/changing-highlighting-level-for-the-current-file.html) for this file to just syntax.

Comment: Also you can easily analyze what is the problem by using VisualVM - you will see GC working too much if you don't have enough heap, or you can Sample CPU and see what is eating it.